# Understand a question from spivak's calculus on manifolds

Tags: calculus

Can someone please explain what does he mean by the second line in the question? what does "A contains at most one point on each horizontal and each vertical line **but boundary A...** means?
[image: question from spivak]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it means that all points from A must be in square

$$0 \le x \le 1, \space\space\space\space 0 \le y \le 1$$

and there are no such x and $ y_1 < y_2 $ that points $(x, y_1)$ and $(x, y_2)$ belong to A

neither such y and $ x_1 < x_2 $ that points $(x_1, y)$ and $(x_2, y)$ belong to A

the boundary of A must be the full square